# ms access: #Name? Error

Tags: ms-access

In my form I have a text field. Control source for the field is `=[MyTable1.MyVal1]*[MyVal2]/100`. This was showing value perfectly so far. But from yesterday it is showing this error `#Name?` in the field. I don't understand what suddenly went wrong. Please help me with how to make this working.

Comment: Check the table for any value that might be "illegal".  By "illegal", I mean anything non-numeric.  Also, if the field could possibly accept NULL values, you should use the Nz() function to change NULLs to 0's, since NULL values will throw errors in arithmetic formulas.

Comment: `[MyTable1.MyVal1]` is a suspect field name, probably due to redudant columns in an underlying query Normally I would expect `[MyTable1].[MyVal1]`

Answer (score 0):

I can't explain why or when this behavior might have changed, but changing the ControlSource to: `=[MyTable1!MyVal1]*[MyVal2]/100` will work, assuming you have valid data.

That is, use an exclamation mark `!` instead of a period `.` between the table name and the field name.